# Confirm x rows are duplicate

Tags: excel, vba

I need a routine that can confirm that there are 3 rows of data for each entry, but don't know where to begin.  As you can see by the below partial table, each row is the same except for the FrgQty and Yield.  I just need something that confirms each Quote# has 3 rows and gives me a message box with the Quote#s that don't have 3 rows.  There are usually anywhere from 1 to 100 quotes in a spreadsheet, so this would help immensely.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. please read the posting guidelines or you will farm downvotes.

Comment: Why are we downvoting him? I don't see what is wrong with his question. Title is effective and the question is clearly stated.

Comment: If you could point out what portion of the guidelines I violated, I'd appreciate it as I don't see it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this subroutine which uses a dictionary object to do this. You'll need to change "Sheet1" to the name of your sheet and "Table1" to the name of the table in your screenshot.

```
Public Sub areThereThreeRowsForEachQuoteNum()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim quoteNumRange As Range

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set quoteNumRange = tbl.ListColumns("Quote#").DataBodyRange.Cells

    'Create a dictionary of quote#, count pairs
    For Each cell In quoteNumRange
        If dict.Exists(cell.Value) = False Then
            dict.Add cell.Value, 1
        Else
            dict(cell.Value) = dict(cell.Value) + 1
        End If
    Next

    'Loop to check for any quote# in the dictionary with count < 3
    'If we find one, show a MsgBox with the problematic Quote#
    For Each key In dict
        If dict(key) < 3 Then
            MsgBox "Quote#" & key & " has only " & dict(key) & " rows."
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what I need, but it put me on the right track.  I can manage from here.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can go without the message box part of the requirement, you don't need VBA for this at all. Just add another column to your table, called `Valid?` or something, and give it the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF([Quote#],[@Quote#])=3
```

Then you can filter that column on `FALSE` to find the offending rows.

Comment: This is another viable option that I may have to look at.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Pivot Table, group by Quote and then count also that same Quote column. That way you can see in around 0.0003 seconds how many Quotes have less than 3 rows, and also, identify which ones.

Comment: I had thought of that and this would work, but I am trying to build macro to help populate a proposal form.  The pivot table approach might still work though.

Comment: Of your records, what do you need to link to your proposal form?